# React state updates but JSX does not

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to show a table with products and its product number. I check to see the state with console.log and the data is visible as expected but the JSX won't update to reflect that when I click the GET Product numbers button.

But when I do some changes in code and save, data shows up in the table. Can't understand why it does not show up one the click itself. I would really appreciate if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

```
import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function Temp() {
  const [products, setproducts] = useState();
  const [productnumbers, setproductnumbers] = useState([]);
  var final = [];

  const productsArray = products?.split(",").map(function (item) {
    return item.trim();
  });

  async function fetchproducts() {
    productsArray.forEach(async (e, i) => {
      await fetch("API URL", productsArray)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          let q = json.styleId.toString();
          final.splice(i, 0, { key: e, value: q });

          return;
        })
        .catch((ERR) => {
          return ERR;
        });
    });
    setproducts("");
    setproductnumbers(final);
    return;
  }

  var unique = productnumbers.filter(
    (ele, ind) =>
      ind ===
      productnumbers.findIndex(
        (elem) => elem.key === ele.key && elem.value === ele.value
      )
  );
  console.log("new-state", productnumbers);

  return (
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <textarea
            value={products}
            onChange={(e) => setproducts(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='Enter products seperated with ","'
            name="skus"
            id="gm-skus"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>{" "}
          <button onClick={fetchproducts}>GET Product numbers</button>
        </div>
        <div className="tableContainer">
          <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td>Products</td>
              <td>Product numbers</td>
            </tr>
            {unique.map((each, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{each.key}</td>
                  <td>{each.value}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </table>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Temp;
```

Also let me know if I need to elaborate on something..

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `unique` variable which is not reactive. To do so, try something like this:

```js
const [unique, setUnique] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => setUnique(productnumbers.filter(
    (ele, ind) =>
      ind ===
      productnumbers.findIndex(
        (elem) => elem.key === ele.key && elem.value === ele.value
      )
  )), [productnumbers]);
```

Now `unique` should be rendered correctly.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the response. I tried your solution but when I click the button the table and console still shows empty array until I save the code once again. The JSX / console.log won't update unless I save the code again. Not sure what's the reason